# How to implement material design spinner

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-spinner

As the Google developer shows material design spinner should be like this
[image]

But in my AppCompat theme, when I drag and drop a spinner, it becomes like this
[image]

There is no bottom border or the little triangle in the corner. How do I achieve the one shown the Google developer website?

Comment: Your AppCompat Spinner is correct Material Design Spinner. The image you posted is old from Holo Theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to images on the [material design spec](http://www.google.com/design/spec/) such as [this one](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bzhp5Z4wHba3bWxmZ1M0UTJBR0E/components_dialogs_fullscreen1.png) the spinner from AppCompat matches the material design theme.

The ones you are showing from the developer site images are from the Holo theme. For example, on the [spinner widget documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) you can see that the spinner control is the holo theme because the `EditText` control in the same image has the edges on its sides.

Comment: I see, but there should be an underline (bottom border) below the spinner. How to put one?

Comment: You can create a custom drawable for your spinner, or just add a simple `<View>` object that draws the underline underneath your spinner.